# Know if object is empty Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, checkbox, angular-ng-if

I'm trying to show a div element only if the user has selected at least one checkbox first. I was trying this in the div:

```
<div class="col-md-1" ng-if="selectedElements.length > 0">
```

selectedElements is declared in my controller like this:

```
$scope.selectedElements = [];
```

works the first time, but when I select a checkbox and then I unselect it the div doesn't disappear.

the checkboxes are declared as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedElements[node.real_id]">
```

The checkboxes are inside a ng-repeat statement, that's the reason to the index in the ng-model.

Comment: Is `node.real_id` a number?

Comment: Yes, it is, comes from a database id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `ng-model` to that will add a Boolean value at the specified index to the array and then just set it to false when you uncheck it. So it will still be present, and `length` will be `> 0`...

Arguably what you want is actually to check is whether there are any items in the array that are true. If that's the case, you can use:

```
<div class="col-md-1" ng-if="selectedElements.some((el) => el)">
```

[`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) takes a function and returns true if the function ever returns true. I've used ECMAScript 2015 syntax. If you're using an older browser:

```
<div class="col-md-1" ng-if="selectedElements.some(function (el) { return el; })">
```

You may need to make a function in your controller for that, but that's the idea.

Answer (score 1):

It works the first time because `ng-model="selectedElements[node.real_id]"` is pushing a value into `selectedElements` at index `node.read_ud`. Thus `selectedElements.length > 1` is true when a checkbox is checked, but also true when you uncheck and `selectedElements[node.real_id]` becomes false, because the element is still in the array.

I think you want something like:

```
<div class="col-md-1" ng-if="selectedCount">

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedElements[node.real_id]" ng-change="onSelect(node.real_id)">
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.selectedCount = 0;

$scope.onSelect = function(id) {
    if ($scope.selectedElements[id]) {
        $scope.selectedCount++;
    } else {
        $scope.selectedCount--;
    }
}
```

Also, `selectedElements` could be an object instead (used like a dictionary).

Comment: I wasn't sure if the ng-model was necessary, different approach, but good solution, thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. The advantage here is that you are not iterating over the array each digest cycle to figure out if any are checked.

Answer (score 0):

I created a function in my controller and used like this:

```
<div class="col-md-1" ng-show="empty(selectedElements)">
```

And in the controller is as follows:

```
$scope.empty = function(data){
    var empty = false;
    angular.forEach(data, function(element, key){
        if(element == true)
            empty = true;
    });
    return empty;
}
```

Comment: If you use a regular `for` loop, you can just return as soon as the first `true` is found instead of continuing to loop. @Mike McCaughan's solution did that using `some`.

Comment: You are totally right. I wasn't thinking about the performance.